# Order by clause with distinct

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table in sql server in which I have some values. For example as below,

```
StationId
-----
3
11
4
```

I have written a query as below,

```
select  STUFF((SELECT distinct (',' + QuoteName(c.StationId))
            FROM Analytics c 
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
        ,1,1,'')
```

where output as below:

```
[11],[3],[4]
```

Now my requirement is I need the output as `[3],[4],[11]`. So when rewrite the query as

```
select  STUFF((SELECT distinct (',' + QuoteName(c.StationId))
            FROM Analytics c ORDER BY c.StationId 
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
        ,1,1,'')
```

I am getting below exception

> ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.

Please give me some suggestions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can alter your code by removing the `DISTINCT` and adding a `GROUP BY` to use with the `ORDER BY`:

```
select  STUFF((SELECT (',' + QuoteName(c.StationId))
            FROM Analytics c 
            group by c.StationId
            ORDER BY c.StationId 
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
        ,1,1,'')
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e92749/1)